# VS 2022 CPU profiling not giving meaningful results when using TPL Dataflow

Tags: profiling, visual-studio-2022, tpl-dataflow

I am trying to figure out where my bottlenecks are in an application that uses TPL Dataflow, and I'm not finding any meaningful results. When I break in my application and look at the CPU usage this is what I'm seeing.

> MyPipelinePopulator (PID 12345) 100%`
> [External Call] System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() 99.65%
> [Unwalkable] 0.34%

My pipeline isn't that complex and consists of three blocks, a batch block to collect data into batches, a processing transform block that can be run concurrently and out of order, and a writing action block that can't run concurrently and must run in order.

I'm assuming that most of my CPU time is spent in the processing block, and I was wanting a breakdown of time spent there, but saying that 99.65% of the CPU time is spent in the ThreadPoolWorkQueue Dispatch is not very helpful.

Is there a way to configure my project so that CPU Usage shows something more helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get useful CPU profiling information by going to `Debug` -> `Performance Profiler...` and then starting the project with `CPU Usage` checked.

The first time I did this, the diagnostic session failed to start and just sat waiting forever for the diagnostic session to start.

I found the solution to that problem on Microsoft's forums https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/592556/diagnostics-session-failed-to-start and apparently there is a service `Visual Studio Standard Collector Service 150` that is sometimes disabled or in my case set to manually start, and it wasn't started. After manually starting that service, then the diagnostic session was able to start.

Comment: You should try using Visual Studio [Concurrency Visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/concurrency-visualizer?view=vs-2022) instead of just CPU profiling. To track performance in production you should use ActivitySource/Activity, and eg OpenTelemetry to collect a trace of each message as it goes through the pipeline. Activity(Source) alone with a custom listener will let you track processing but pushing traces to eg [Jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.18/#trace-detail-view) will allow you ty see what's actually going on without hampering your application